# How to describe this validation requirement in jsonschema?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I want to validate my API json response like this:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "results": [
     {"type":1, "abc": 123},
     {"type":2, "def": 456}
  ]
}
```

I want to validate the objects within results to have a "abc" field when its type is 1, and "def" field when its type is 2. The results may contain arbitrary number of type1 and type2 objects.

Can I specify this in jsonschema? Or must I use a generic validator for elements in `results` and do validation myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `anyOf` keyword.

> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if it validates successfully against at least one schema defined by this keyword's value.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor85

You need to define both types of items and then use `anyOf` To describe the array items for "results".

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "code": { "type": "integer" },
    "results": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/resultItems" }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "resultItems": {
      "type": "object",
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/type1" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/type2" }
      ]
    },
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [1] },
        "abc": { "type": "integer" }
      },
      "required": ["abc"]
    },
    "type2": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [2] },
        "def": { "type": "integer" }
      },
      "required": ["def"]
    }
  }
}
```